# Has anyone seen/read interspecies competition that is different at spatial scale for the same group of animals?

Tags: zoology, ecology, ethology, community-ecology

I work at a highly fragmented wildlife sanctuary in North Borneo, Malaysia. We have 8 species of hornbills here and from our observation they've grown to be less territorial in terms of where they forage for food. Our friends in the mainland of Malaysia have observed differently - these hornbills are territorial even in the areas they forage, rather than just during breeding season or around their nesting trees.

Do you think the limited resources for space and food where I work force them to be less territorial than their counterparts that live in areas with more forest cover (thus more space and food)?

I'd love to hear or read more observations like this from different areas, if any of you have anything to share.